# How to receive SMS using Android service with BroadcastReceiver without GUI

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I have been working on an application that use to receive SMS and show a Toast using **Broadcast Receiver** and i have an activity with no purpose, when i removed that activity and build the apk and run on my phone, application is not responding when SMS is received (no Toast showing), although remaining code is same as it was previously. Can anyone help please i am so stuck and couldn't help myself reading hundreds of answers. I studied i should create a service but still no Toast is appearing. below is my code. I can not have any GUI in my application even don't want to have auto kill activity.

**BroadcastReceiver.java**

```
package com.test.testservice;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
    private static final String LOG = "SmsBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intentExtras != null) {
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);


            if (sms != null)
            {
                String smsMessageStr = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i)
                {
                    SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                    String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                    String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

                    smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                    smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //MyService objService=new MyService();
                //objService.startService(intent);
                //objService.stopService(intent);


                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
                //myIntent.putExtra("Sender", Sender);
                //myIntent.putExtra("Fullsms", Fullsms);
                context.startService(myIntent);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
package com.test.testservice;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String LOG = "MyService";
    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        if (super.stopService(name))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"HELLO stopService",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(LOG, "stopService");
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ComponentName startService(Intent service) {
        return super.startService(service);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this,"HELLO onCreate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this,"HELLO onStart",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.test.testservice">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

    <service android:name="com.test.testservice.service.MyService"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can i create a service without any GUI and install it on phone? Then create a separate app to run that service, and once the service run i uninstall that second app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are creating your own phone, or your own custom ROM, you need the activity. Your `BroadcastReceiver` will not work when your app is first installed. It will only start to work once the user has launched your activity (or something else uses an explicit `Intent` to start one of your components).

> I can not have any GUI in my application

Then your app will not work on Android 3.1+ devices, which make up the *vast* majority of the Android device ecosystem.